# How can I change the postgres random_page_cost on Heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

On a Heroku-managed instance of postgres the default value for `random_page_cost` is 2.0.  I'd like to change the value, but don't see a way to do so.  How can I change that value?

Answer (score 2):

You can alter the database to get the number you want.

```
alter database mydb set random_page_cost=1.4;
```

Comment: Doing things locally at least requires me to restart the database, which I assume would also be required in a Heroku-hosted DB and involve downtime.  Is there another option?

Comment: No alter user / database is immediate. Note that old connections will not get the change, they have to disconnect and reconnect.

Comment: Note that alter user overrides alter db settings and alter db settings override alter system.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this can be done at the connection level, with no change required to the database.